# typeError: form.serialize is not a function - What am I missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I'm not sure what I'm missing, but this code is throwing the a typeError: form.serialize is not a function

```
$('#paragraphsList').on('change', 'input', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = this.closest("form");
    console.log(form);
    console.log(form.serialize());
```

The form is dynamically created, but the console.log output for the form variable shows that it is finding the correct form.

```
<ul id="paragraphsList">
<--dynamicaly generated content begins here-->
    <li>
        <form class="paragraphForm" name="80" id="80">
            <input id="81" name="activity"  value="a" class="paragraphs">
            <input id="82" name="task"      value="b" class="paragraphs">
            <input id="83" name="pStyle"    value="c" class="paragraphs">
            <input id="84" name="pContent"  value="d" class="paragraphs,style2">
        </form>
    </li>
    <li>
        <form class="paragraphForm" name="85" id="85">
            <input id="86" name="activity"  value="a" class="paragraphs">
            <input id="87" name="task"      value="b" class="paragraphs">
            <input id="88" name="pStyle"    value="c" class="paragraphs">
            <input id="89" name="pContent"  value="d" class="paragraphs,style2">
        </form>
    </li>
    .....
```

Sorry for the late updates.... here is a full page that demonstrates the problem. If you look at the console output, the on-change is obviously being called in the correct place, and has the correct form object, but the serialize call still fails.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p onclick="load()">Load Forms</p>
    <ul id="paragraphsList">

    </ul>

</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function load() {
    $('#paragraphsList').empty();
    $('#paragraphsList').append(newForm("A", "step1", "task1", "myStyle1", "myContent1"));
    $('#paragraphsList').append(newForm("b", "step2", "task2", "myStyle2", "myContent2"));
    $('#paragraphsList').append(newForm("c", "step3", "task3", "myStyle3", "myContent3"));
    $('#paragraphsList').append(newForm("d", "step4", "task4", "myStyle4", "myContent4"));
}

function newForm(id, activity, task, pStyle, pContent) {
    var li = $('<li></li>');
    var form = $("<form></form>");
    form.attr("class", "paragraphForm");
    form.attr("name", id);
    form.attr("id", id);
    form.append(newField(id, "activity",    activity,   "paragraphs", "data" ));
    form.append(newField(id, "task",        task,       "paragraphs", "data" ));
    form.append(newField(id, "pStyle",      pStyle,     "paragraphs", "data" ));
    form.append(newField(id, "pContent",    pContent,   "paragraphs," + pStyle, "data"));
    form.change(function () {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.serialize());
    });
    li.append(form);
    return li;
}

function newField(id, name, value, style) {
    var input = $("<input>");
    input.attr("id", id + "." + name);
    input.attr("name", name);
    input.attr("value", value);
    input.attr("class", style);
    return input;
}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: If you go for the option of closest('form') your javascript code will be depending on the positioning of your markup.

Comment: I'm listening for changes on "input" objects, and want to work with that input objects parent form.... so I'm still pretty convinced that closest('form') is correct. The console.log(form) statement works and shows that I've got the correct form selected.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a selector for the id `paragraphsList`, which is missing on your form. -- ah, it would be nice if you'd shown that it's the parent in the snippet.

I think you need to select the input field, and then call the 'on-click' on that. That way 'this' refers to the input field instead of the container of the form.

```
$('#paragraphsList > form > input')
```

Comment: paragraphList is a <ul> that sit's above all the forms. The code is executing, it doesn't fail till it gets to the serialize() call.

Comment: the output shown above is from console.log(form) - it is finding the correct form, and executing at the correct time.

Comment: @MikeStorey: even an object assigned 'null' is still an object. Which does not have the 'serialize' function. cale_b is right.

Comment: I have to listen for the on-change event from the <ul> because all of the <li> members (where the forms are located) are dynamically generated. When I attempt to attach the on("change" listener to any of the generated content it never fires. The code is finding the correct form, it just can't serialize it.

Comment: @cale_b - When the input changes, I want the closest parent "form" object, so I believe .closest is the correct thing to use here. console.log(form) is printing out the correct form.

Answer (score 2):

This could be solved as is said in documentation from jquery serialize:

```
$( ".paragraphForm" ).on( "change", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log( $( this ).serialize() );
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>serialize demo</title>
  <style>
  body, select {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  form {
    margin: 5px;
  }
  p {
    color: red;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  b {
    color: blue;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
  <select name="single">
    <option>Single</option>
    <option>Single2</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <select name="multiple" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected="selected">Multiple</option>
    <option>Multiple2</option>
    <option selected="selected">Multiple3</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1" id="ch1">
  <label for="ch1">check1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check2" checked="checked" id="ch2">
  <label for="ch2">check2</label>

  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio1" checked="checked" id="r1">
  <label for="r1">radio1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio2" id="r2">
  <label for="r2">radio2</label>
</form>

<p><tt id="results"></tt></p>

<script>
  function showValues() {
    var str = $( "form" ).serialize();
    $( "#results" ).text( str );
  }
  $( "input[type='checkbox'], input[type='radio']" ).on( "click", showValues );
  $( "select" ).on( "change", showValues );
  showValues();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have added the e parameter and the call to preventDefault() and the functionality is still the same. I believe the parameter is optional, and as I don't use it.... at any rate the code is executing at the correct time, just the serialize function is failing.

Comment: serialize function is only for forms

Comment: Thats an example of jquery ui on how to show values of a serialize of a form... listening to the change event on your select or inputs

Comment: I have updated the code snippet.... the variable form is pointing to the correct form. console.log(form) shows the proper form is selected. I can not attach the onChange listener to the form or input's because they are dynamically added to the page and so never receive the on-change event.

Comment: then the moment you attach those events should be in the correct moment so they are actually rendered and they can have the on-change event

Comment: that depends on your app, sometimes could be the on ready event of jquery sometimes not :)

Comment: can  you please explain how to attach an event listener to a dynamically created piece of content. I have not been able to get this to work and was advised to listen for the on change event in a parent element that was present at $('document').ready()

Comment: sure i will make a little sample on document ready event with a form

Answer (score 1):

The variable "form" above is a "regular" object and not a DOM object. 
This code works

```
console.log($(form).serialize());
```

Evidently this.closest('form') returns a regular object when I expected it to be a DOM object. I'm still a bit confused about the difference between **this** and **$(this)** and why the response from this.closest("form") is not a DOM object. Any clarification on the topic is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Listening to dynamic content on ready

```
<ul id="paragraphsList">

</ul>


$(document).ready(function () {
    var form = $('<li><form class="paragraphForm" id="form1" name="80" id="80"><input id="81" name="activity"  value="a" class="paragraphs"><input id="82" name="task"      value="b" class="paragraphs"><input id="83" name="pStyle"    value="c" class="paragraphs"><input id="84" name="pContent"  value="d" class="paragraphs,style2"></form></li>');
    $('#paragraphsList').append(form);
    $("input").click(function () {
        alert('you clicked me');
        console.log($('form').serialize());
    });
});
```

Here is the content created dynamically and listening to a click event.

Comment: May be you just need to change the click event to the event you want to listent, and the alert for the $('form').serialize() you need

Comment: also you could add a better selector than an input selector :) so you just listen to those elements in the page that you need.

Comment: Ok, so if you place a $('#paragraphsList').empty(); statement in the code above, it does not work. The code that populates the paragraphList resets the list and then populates it, and the .empty() seems to break jQuery listeners.

Comment: sure, if you make empty it will actually remove it from dom and all the listeners to it

Comment: Why did you do empty? It is rendered with something inside?

Comment: You can do it better with method chaining, like this . item.attr(attr, value).attr(attr, val);

Comment: You could avoid so many calls to Dom by doing in it in a string append it all at once